# Parsing pairs of Strings and Double-Vectors using Scanner?

Tags: java, string, parsing, java.util.scanner

I'm fairly new to parsing text files with java. My task is, 
I have a text file that contains strings and Double values as follows (example):

word 0.6478 1.74837 -0.2734 3.3475nextword 4.94756 -0.46372 3.29384 0.36475thirdword 5.92836 (...)

(and so on)

so the file contains words followed by a consistent number of lets say n numerical values which are in some way associated to the word they follow. What I want in the end is a Set of Strings containing all the words from the files and for every word the associated vector of n Doubles.

My first idea was to use the java.util.Scanner but as far as i know it only reads Items separated by spaces and as you can see from my example there are no spaces between the last number of a group and the next word.

So is there an easy way to fix this while using the Scanner or an even easier one with a different parsing tool?

I'm grateful for any tips

UPDATE:

I have another problem. My input file contains exponential numbers like: -2.1961e-05
Which my scanner reads into the number: -2.1961 and the word: e-05

is there even a chance to resolve these kind of numbers?

Comment: Another problem deserves another question. Hint: more people are observing *new* question queue than edited (*active*) question queue so posting new question would also increase your chances of getting an answer. Anyway I updated my answer to include case you described in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default Scanner is using only whitespaces (including tabs and line separators) as delimiters. But if you are familiar with regex (regular expressions) you can set your own delimiter to:

- whitespaces `\s`

OR places which have

- digit before `(?<=\d)`
- and don't have digit after it `(?!\d)`
- excluding case where after digit is dot `.` (because `12.34a` only `34` `a` should be separated) `(?![.])`.

(I used positive and negative look-ahead mechanism from regex here. More info at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

So you can set up your Scanner like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(yourData);
sc.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);//some locales use 12,34 for double, English ensures 12.34 format
sc.useDelimiter("\\s|(?<=\\d)(?!\\d)(?![.])");
```

---

RE UPDATE:

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\s|(?<=\\d)(?!\\d)(?![.]|[eE]-?\\d+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (without Scanner) is to tokenise each line with a simple regex and then parse each token:

```
String line = "word 0.6478 1.74837 -0.2734 3.3475nextword 4.94756 -0.46372 3.29384 0.36475thirdword 5.92836";
String nonNumeric = "[^\\d.-]";
//alternative: nonNumeric="[a-zA-Z\\s]"
List<Double> doubles = Arrays
    .asList(line.split(nonNumeric))
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .map(s -> Double.parseDouble(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(doubles);
```

Result:

```
[0.6478, 1.74837, -0.2734, 3.3475, 4.94756, -0.46372, 3.29384, 0.36475, 5.92836]
```